# Unrouted React component not updating when Route changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My React app has a Header component which resides inside the Router component, but is, of course, not routed. For some reason, when the route changes, the Header does not update. It doesn't even check if it needs to update. There is an area in the Header that needs to change based on the current url, so this is a problem. I even tried passing in the current url as a prop, but it didn't seem to even notice the change.
Here is the App.js render method:

```js
          return (
            <div style={s.appContainer}>
              <Router>
                <Header
                  user={this.state.user}
                  style={s.header}
                  dataLoaded={this.state.dataLoaded}
                />
                <div style={s.content}>
                  <Route path='/app/v2/reports'>
                    <ReportContainer user={this.state.user}/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path='/app/v2/groups'>
                    <CourseContainer user={this.state.user}/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route exact={true} path='/app/v2/people'>
                    <PeopleContainer/>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path='/app/v2/people/:email' component={UserDetailsContainer} />
                  <Route path='/app/v2/lessons/:lesson_id' component={LessonDetailsContainer} />
                  <Route exact={true} path='/app/v2/learning/library' component={LearnerLibraryContainer} />
                  <Route exact={true} path='/app/v2' component={DashboardContainer} />
                </div>
              </Router>
            </div>
          )
```

I can't share most of the header, but this method is the part that is trying to check the url:

```js
  inLearnerMode() {
    const currentPath = window.location.href || '';
    return currentPath.includes('learning')
  }
```

Comment: show us the code of header and also what you exactly need there *?

Comment: I've added what I can. The code in the Header is working, the problem is that when the route changes, the App component doesn't re-render, so I need some way to trigger the Header to re-render. I've confirmed this by inserting a `ShouldComponentUpdate` method in the Header with a log statement, and it's not being called.

Comment: Are using class component or functional ?

Comment: Class component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap up the Header component with [withrouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC , then you could access current location using passed props to your component ,
so you component should look like :

```
...
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...


class Header extends React.Component {
  
  

  inLearnerMode() {
    const { location } = this.props;
    const currentPath = location.pathname || '';
    return currentPath.includes('learning')
  }
  
  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header)
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing! The only thing is that the `location` object being included doesn't have a `href` property. I had to use the `pathname` property on it instead. Once I fixed that it worked perfectly, though, thank you so much.